# Last value in two levels of group by in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following data set:

```
2018-01-02  Oranges 1479    1480
2018-01-03  Oranges 1478    1504
2018-01-04  Oranges 1507    1494
2018-01-05  Oranges 1510    1551
2018-01-02  Apples  2150    2196
2018-01-03  Apples  2161    2167
2018-01-04  Apples  2192    2169
2018-01-05  Apples  2169    2194
```

I'd like to get the following result:

```
2018-00 Oranges 1479    1551
2018-00 Apples  2150    2194
```

Where:

```
2018-00     Oranges   1479                        1551
year-week   grouped   first value third column    last value fourth column
```

Is there a way to do this in one query with MySQL? 
My query actually is that:

```
select 
    CONCAT(YEAR(date), '/', WEEK(date)) week, 
    fruit, 
    init, 
    something_like_last_column_value_fn(end)
from fruits_flow
    where CONCAT(YEAR(date), '/', WEEK(date)) = '2018/0'
    and fruits in ('Oranges', 'Apples')
group by week, fruit;
```

I'm limiting in where clause only to test.

The third column value is easy because after group is the first value in line. But the last value of forth column, I really tried a lot of things and zero success.

Comment: So when you say first value, is that the first per Fruit, and for the first day in the week? What MySQL version?

Comment: I got this far [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ad8db50c19b244312a32dd3fd3cd40d7). Wrong end value. Out of time. hoping someone can correct.

Comment: @danblack *Wrong end value.* Not the first time I've seen LAST_VALUE return an incorrect value. I try not to use it.

Comment: @Akina, thanks for the tip. created https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19017

Comment: See the tag I added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONCAT(YEAR(`date`),'/',WEEK(`date`)) as `week`,
    fruit,
    FIRST_VALUE(init) OVER (PARTITION BY fruit,`week` 
                            ORDER BY `date` ASC) AS 'first',
    FIRST_VALUE(end) OVER (PARTITION BY fruit,`week` 
                           ORDER BY `date` DESC) AS 'last'
FROM fruits_flow
```